# "Это как раз из серии когда..." - наличие "серии" не провоцирует постановку запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

> Это как раз из серии когда исполнителей ролей нашумевшего не так давно
>   американского телефильма «Война и мир» спросили, что они думают о
>   романе Толстого, а они чистосердечно признались, что произведения
>   этого не знают и не понимают, зачем его читать.

Comment: Это серия фильма или воображаемая серия ситуаций?

Comment: Воображаемая серия ситуаций.

Comment: Каков смысл фразы? Описывается один случай из серии подобных?  Тогда в предыдущей фразе должна быть описана эта "серия".

Comment: М_Г, из серии - это как из оперы, это идиома.

Comment: Не очень вас понимаю. Вы пишете: "Воображаемая серия ситуаций". По вашему мнению, текст, идущий после "когда", описывает всю серию или лишь один случай из этой серии?

Comment: Слово идиома Вам знакомо? )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обыденный язык, положенный на бумагу в части фразы, не распространяясь на всю, здесь выглядит странно. Начинать надо так: «Это как раз из серии случаев, когда...».